# ExcelPackage can't read xlsx worksheet

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

My `ExcelPackage` was working fine (xlsx) and I can read data, then I got new Excel file to import and all of sudden `ExcelPackage` stopped working.
After debug I found that `excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets` is `null` and can't read worksheet.

One of my colleague asked me to SaveAs file and run code. I did accordingly and it's working now but it will not work for me because I used this code to download file from sftp server and there is hangfire routine which reads this file once a week, so it is auto routine where I can't save file before read.

```cs
public void ReadExcelFile(Stream stream, string worksheet)
{
   var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream);
   var worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheet];
}
```

I expect from reader to read worksheet.

Comment: You used same var name for the worksheet name and Worksheet instance. Can you change that and try again.

Comment: yup its my sample code i did but still not working. public void ReadExcelFile(Stream stream, string worksheet)
{
   var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream);
   var _worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[worksheet];
}

Comment: The meta data that makes an Excel file is possibly not written to the downloaded file. In such case save the file through code in a temporary location and then read the worksheet.

Comment: i tried and not working.

Comment: it is probably xls binary format file with xlsx extension. EPPlus seems to support only the Open XML format (xlsx). You can verify by opening the file in Notepad or similar, and check if it starts with "PK" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures